# How Do I get a URL parameter passed into a django CBV?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I have a urls.py file setup as follows

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', BlogListView.as_view()),
    url(r'(?P<blog_id>)\d{1,}/$', BlogDetailView.as_view())
)
```

with the correlating view

```
class BlogDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, blog_id, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Blog.objects.get(post_id=blog_id).to_detail_json
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(post), mimetype='application/json')
```

I get an error when I visit 127.0.0.1:8000/blog/1/

```
ValueError at /blog/4/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

but if I change

```
post = Blog.objects.get(post_id=blog_id).to_detail_json
```

to

```
post = Blog.objects.get(post_id=1).to_detail_json
```

then I get the correct response.

In case it is wanted, here is my model

```
from mongoengine import *
from collections import OrderedDict

import datetime
import json

class Blog(Document):
    post_id = IntField(unique=True)
    title = StringField(max_length=144, required=True)
    date_created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    body = StringField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.schema = {
        "title": self.title,
        "date": str(self.date_created),
        "id": self.post_id,
        "body": self.body
    }
            super(Blog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    @property
    def to_detail_json(self):
        fields = ["id","title", "date", "body"]
        return {key:self.schema[key] for key in fields}

    @property
    def to_list_json(self):
        fields = ["title", "date"]
        return {key:self.schema[key] for key in fields}
```

---

## Update

I changed the BlogDetailView to return

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(self.kwargs),mimetype='application/json')
```

and it gives me

```
{
    blog_id: ""
}
```

Which leads me to believe it is something with my urls.py file, but I do not see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that

```
url(r'(?P<blog_id>)\d{1,}/$', BlogDetailView.as_view())
```

should be

```
url(r'(?P<blog_id>\d{1,})/$', BlogDetailView.as_view())
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
post = Blog.objects.get(post_id=self.kwargs['blog_id']).to_detail_json
```

Comment: you're welcome, btw is better to answer your self question and mark it as a resolution.